# Can replacing a low voltage wire actually make the air handler blower blow more air?

Tags: wiring, fans, voltage

Our system stopped cooling, it is 11 months old. The service tech found a low voltage wire running from the handler to the outside unit bad. He showed me the wire was not connected but dead now, after 36 some years it was in the wall. When replaced the system started cooling again plus it seems the air handler runs noticably faster. Is this my imagination or can replacing a low voltage wire increase the fan speed?

Comment: PS: I know almost nothing about electricity! Just an invisible force - God like I think!

Comment: We'll need more info on makes and models of your equipment to give good advice.   When you say you "replaced the system", what does that mean? The outdoor unit, the air handler or both? There are usually settings on the air-handler than control fan speed, perhaps the tech adjusted it to run faster, maybe to match it to a new outdoor unit?   You just haven't provided enough info yet to give better advice.  Please take the tour and edit your question to include more details.

Comment: Low voltage usually as to do with control system.  Control can turn on a switch to make something work with higher power.  Low voltage wire might have been on a slow wear down over time, still it just broke completely.

Comment: No. Low voltage tells line voltage to engage or not, *'there is no try'*. Presumably they did their job, part of which is arbitrarily changing the filter. If you use pleated filters and they put in a fiberglass, you will notice a marked improvement in air flow, and a slight decrease in air quality.

Comment: Some units use a "universal" ECM that may have low voltage speed control signals. So I think the answer is yes, under some circumstances. As mentioned above, make and model would be required to know for sure.

Comment: @Ggeiser did the service tech only replace the wire, or did the tech replace the wire and altered the connection?

Comment: Yes, can you post information about the make and model of all equipment involved please?

Comment: More info: New Amana three ton - replaced both the air handler and the outside unit. Ducts etc. all still the old stuff - the replaced wire inside the wall was original and never replaced since mid 80s. Why I am asking is because the guy who replaced everything is not the guy fixing it. In fact, he got all pissed off because I hired someone else and when he saw the unit partially apart, he yelled that the low voltage wire wasn't the problem!

Comment: The guy who fixed it only replaced the wire.

Answer (score 0):

On some units there are outdoor units with 2 speed control I just replaced one a few weeks ago. 1 terminal on the motor was 830 rpm and the other 1100? This was an older model but if the low speed was only connected it would have only that speed. Not sure I am following an 11 month old unit with 35yr old wiring in the wall but if the system had a dual speed motor or better it is possible that a speed selector being hooked up could make a change.